# Bloomberg API - get list of government bonds

Tags: c#, java, .net, api, bloomberg

When hitting KENGB <Govt> <GO> on the Bloomberg terminal I get **list of all** Kenya **government bonds**.

**How do I get this list through [Bloomberg API](http://www.openbloomberg.com/files/2012/03/blpapi-developers-guide.pdf)? Or list of their tickers?**

<sub>(I download PX_LAST prices and historical prices for various securities regularly, so I am pretty familiar with service "//blp/refdata" and request "ReferenceDataRequest" ... but cannot figure out how to retrieve list of securities (and its tickers) programmatically)</sub>

Comment: You can query fields through the API but I don't think you can query instruments. So you would need to save the list somewhere and read it from your program... You can always ask HELP HELP to check if they have a better idea.

Answer (score 2):

try to take a look at this:

http://www.openbloomberg.com/content/uploads/sites/2/2013/04/blpapi-developers-guide.pdf

at page 77 it explains which service you must call to have Government Bonds.

this is teh c++ code:

```
 Service govtService = session.getService("//blp/instruments");
 Request request = govtService.createRequest("govtListRequest");
 request.asElement().setElement("partialMatch", true);
 request.asElement().setElement("query", "T*");// this plus the previous line permits to retrieve all the thicker that begins with T
 request.asElement().setElement("ticker", "LANG_OVERRIDE_NONE");
 request.asElement().setElement("maxResults", 10);
 sendRequest(request, session);
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know to get a list of securities via API v3 is to use the EQS API where you set up an EQS screen and then use the API to get the matching securities. Not sure if this lets you achieve the same result you get from security search on the Terminal.